# What is the meaning of -999 degrees Celsius?

Tags: meteorology, weather-forecasting

I was checking the weather forecast just now, and it is showing that it "feels like -999 °C". I never heard or saw -999 °C before. I searched other weather channels, and they were showing that it feels like 2 °C. What is the meaning of -999 °C, irrespective of the weather?

Comment: That means its cold.  Really really cold.  So cold that they really don't know how cold it actually feels.  OR it just means that a programmer screwed up.

Comment: @ChrisLively Or there was missing data in one of the input fields to their "feels like" algorithm. It probably isnt a straight wind chill and may depend on more than just temp and wind.

Comment: [Oh, the weather outside is frightful.](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/Oh-The-Weather-Outside-is-Frightful)

Comment: @casey: a programmer is still supposed to take those types of things into account...

Comment: This really sounds like a mistake to me!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The value -999 is likely the "fill value" used in the dataset when data is missing or is not being properly filtered or handled when displayed.  In the specific case on the website you cite, it is likely a problem with the algorithm for wind chill (the "feels like" temperature this time of year).

It isn't a physical value and only means the value is missing. Furthermore, -999°C is not a possible value because [absolute zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_zero) is –273.15°C, and it's not possible to be colder than this (at least [not in any meaningful way](http://www.nature.com/news/quantum-gas-goes-below-absolute-zero-1.12146), and certainly not because of wind chill). The [coldest recorded temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_temperature_recorded_on_Earth) on earth is around –90°C.

Comment: Personally, I prefer -9e99 (or 9e99) as a dubious (and obvious) fill value. But yes, this is almost certainly what this is.

Comment: NASA often uses -9999... just to be sure they put the extra 9

Comment: the data on that page comes from weather underground, see http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=resources/phrase-glossary 'values will = -9999 or -999 for Null or Non applicable (NA) variables' I also suspect that 'feels like' is the heat index value, not the wind chill, which is why it's undefined ( you're not going to get heat stroke there at the moment )

Comment: @PeteKirkham "feels like" is typically heat index in the warm season and wind chill in the cold season.  Some provides use additional factors in their algorithm as well.

Comment: Stupid languages that don't have an `NA` numeric value >:/

Comment: No, it isn't stupid. For analytical purposes spreadsheets necessarily have a numerical field, so we have to insert a 'stupid' number that we can recognize as spurious, and filter out when it comes to statistical analysis.